# Waves that have no horizontal motion

Tags: waves

I've been told in class that if we look on a certain point on a wave, we would see that it remains in the same horizontal position and only moves up and down.

I'm really having trouble imaging that. How can you visualize it?

Do all waves behave this way?

Why is there no movement in the horizontal line?

Are there waves that do both of the movements - horizontal and vertical?

Thanks

Comment: Imagine tying a string to a pillar and shaking the other end, to make a wave. The string has to be only moving vertically; it can't be moving horizontally, because it's fixed by the pillar and your hand.

Comment: Only "transverse waves" behave this way, that is, waves which are a disturbance normal to the medium. Longitudinal waves, such as sound, are not amenable to this perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way of demonstrating transverse waves is the [Bell wave machine](http://www.physics.montana.edu/demonstrations/apparatus/3_oscillationsandwaves/demos/belllabswavemachine.html).  It consists of a few dozzen parallel rigid rods attached at their centres to a flexible spine.

You can see it in action in [this short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wqKIs3Hf64), or [this longer classic film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DovunOxlY1k) featuring its original inventor.  Note that the rods only move in the vertical direction and not horizontally.

Waves on the surface of water, particulary ones that are larger than ripples, are more complex with water particles exhibiting both vertical and horizontal motion in various proportions depending on their depth.  See [this HyperPhysics page](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/watwav2.html)  for example.

Answer (score 1):

[via GIPHY](http://giphy.com/gifs/maths-sine-wave-woooooooooooo-fv81HOdCFbfRS)

Image the wave being light and the line with the ball on being a wall. Let's say your point of view is in the wall towards the incoming wave. As the ball on the wave suggests the wave is just moving up and down from that perspective.

Comment: If some nows how to embed this GIF in the post itself?